# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mqtt'

Tags: python

I'm trying to run flask-mqtt on raspberry pi. I am running python version 3.7.3 it looks like I can't update python to 3.10 on pi. I don't know if that is necessary. I have installed flask-mqtt with following command

`pip install Flask-MQTT:`

> Requirement already satisfied: Flask-MQTT in /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.0.7) 
> Requirement already satisfied: Flask in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from Flask-MQTT) (1.0.2)
>
> Requirement already satisfied: paho-mqtt in /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask-MQTT) (1.6.1) 
> Requirement already satisfied: typing; python_version < "3.5" in /home/pi/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Flask-MQTT) (3.10.0.0)

I have both tried running app.py in virtual environment and directly on pi system
everytime I run it i get ModuleNotFoundError like following

> Traceback (most recent call last): 
> File "app.py", line 2, in  
> from flask_mqtt import Mqtt 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_mqtt'

I am running Raspberry Pi OS (Legacy) on Raspberry Pi model 3 b+

Comment: You're installing under Python 2.7 packages. Do you have another version of `pip` available, like `pip3` or `python3-pip`?

Comment: You may have more than one python. For instance, your pip is installing into python 2.7. It may be that pip3 works. Or, maybe `python3 -m pip install Flask-MQTT`

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved!

the issue had something to do with port numbers. seems like I was always trying to run on port 80. when I changed to other ports, for example 8080 it worked. I am not sure why because nothing else is listening to port 80 I tried Following

> telnet 192.168.8.175 80

and no connection

the final solution was to change...

```
if __name__ == '__main__': <br>
   app.run(debug=True, port=80, host='0.0.0.0') <br>
```

to...

```
if __name__ == '__main__':    
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Thanks for the help!